# Prolog memory issues

Tags: prolog, profiling, swi-prolog, yap

I'd like to find a way to profile the memory usage of a predicate (a huge one) I've written in prolog. I'm currently running it with [swi](http://www.swi-prolog.org/) and [yap](http://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/~vsc/Yap/documentation.html) and I can see from those processes memory consumption that a big chunk of memory gets allocated.

The problem is that it does not get deallocated/freed/garbage collected when the predicate terminates (I have to halt the interpreter to see it back) plus the amount of memory only keeps *growing* while the predicate is running (wheather it shall not since tail recursion optimization should mitigate the issue, I guess, at each iteration).

Is there a way to spot the subpredicate/call that increases the memory used and check if the tail recursion optimization is effectively being called?

Any other suggestion on how to optimize the issue will be very appreciated. I will give more details about what the predicate is doing if those are necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SWI-Prolog, one easy way to see if your recursive predicate is actually getting tail-optimization is using `prolog_current_frame` ([look here](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27B.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/manipstack.html%27%29%29)):

```
foo :-
    prolog_current_frame(F), format('~d~n',[F]),
    do_something,
    foo.
```

If tail-optimization was performed, it will return the same integer each time you enter your predicate with a recursive call. I have had the problem that I do not realize that a predicate I am using is creating choice points and preventing tail-optimization.

If no tail optimization is the actual problem, then something else you could do is simply put a cut before the recursive call:

```
foo :-
    do_something,
    !, foo.
```

This will remove any choice points created by `do_something`. If your memory use is still growing then the problem might be somewhere else. Is your predicate creating a large data structure? or using a lot of intermediate lists?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on spotting the last call optimization. A simple and manual way to check for the unoptimise code is to call prolog_current_frame/1 in each cycle. I am seeing that the predicate is recognized by yap too but its value changes sometimes (it is not the same as swi with the added cut) so I guess it is not reliable (I'm running it to check the memory consumption now It will take 1hr : ))

Comment: Basically I'm doing some ILP work, loading from a big file ~7000 examples (as a ~500 literal bodies clause each) and doing a generalization/refinement of my current best hypotesis that explains them all. I'm heavly using association lists and creating/handling long lists at each iteration.

Comment: @rano This is indeed how I meant it, calling `prolog_current_frame(Frame)` each cycle, _Frame_ should not change is tail optimization was performed. I don't know if this holds for YAP.

Comment: I guess I will not get any more replies about some way to memory profiling my prolog programs, so I will mark this answer as the correct one since it partially fulfills my needs and was very useful to resolve one of my issues.